# Google Sheet create a hyperlink() like function to open Pop Up message

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-docs

In Google Sheet, I like to create a general JS/GS function similar to the Hyperlink() function so that I can quickly create a Pop Up message without creating so many JS script.

While we can create all kinds of AppScript function that accept a text variable as the pop up content, the challenge is that we cannot trigger it unless we create some kind of buttons or add a menu option. Both adding button is cumbersome to create and it is not conveniently sized and fixed within a cell. If I have many of such pop up messages across the sheet, it will be pretty difficult to create so many buttons. I have searched all over the net and cannot even find someone asking a similar question not to mention a solution.
The most efficient way is a function which is similar to the hyperlink() function where I can just add the contents of the Pop Up dialog box. I can image the product will be something like the mock up image below.

Please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkFNk.png)

Comment: At first, in the current stage, I think that there are not hyperlinks for directly opening a dialog on Spreadsheet. In order to open the dialog on Spreadsheet, for example, it is required to use the methods of `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert()` and `Browser.msgBox()`. And, in order to run the script, it is required to use Web Apps. But these methods cannot be used at the Web Apps. It seems that this is the current specification. So in the current stage, I think that your goal cannot be achieved. I apologize for this.

Comment: What would be your use case, have you thought of other options that may work for you?

Comment: The use case is to display information in static or dynamic case. The picture shown in my original post is the most common use case: to display help message. The content, however, can be dynamic based on information extracted from other cells. The application is endless. The issue is not how to open the pop up or dialog box, the issue is building a trigger as part of the spreadsheet without the overhead need in creating buttons or menu option and associating with Javascript. If we have a hyperlink() like function, ordinary user can create ad hoc messages without involving Appscript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger to show the alert. Inside this `onEdit()` you can set the conditions you want to be applied and set multiple alerts to show.

It is not a ton of code if you want to keep it simple.